# injection in a Dart singleton with angular2

Tags: dart, singleton, angular

Hi have this singleton class:

```
class Singleton {
  static final Singleton _singleton = new Singleton._internal();

  factory Singleton() {
    return _singleton;
  }

  Singleton._internal();
}
```

i want to inject a Logger inside my class in this way:

```
class Singleton {
  static final Singleton _singleton = new Singleton._internal();

  factory Singleton( @Inject(LoggerService) this.log) {
    return _singleton;
  }

  Singleton._internal();
}
```

but it seem that Factory doesn't not support the injection.

Comment: Sounds like Angular2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion this is the wrong approach in Angular. Angular DI provides singletons by itself.

```
class Singleton {
  final LoggerService log;

  Singleton(this.log);
}
```

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [LoggerService, Singleton]);
```

should do what you want. As long as you don't add `Singleton` to providers elsewhere (for example on a component) Angular2 will always inject the same instance.

If you still want to keep above pattern, use

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    LoggerService, 
    provide(Singleton, 
        useFactory: (log) => new Singleton(log), 
        deps: [LoggerService])
]);
```

Comment: Perfect @Günter. It works better with this pattern :)

Comment: What is the preferred solution now that `bootstrap()` has been replaced with `runApp()`?